# No library found for org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresOptimizer

Tags: java, processing, apache-commons-math

I am importing Apache Commons Math and Lemmingapex Trilateration as external jar libraries in Processing. I followed this instruction from SO:

[How to add external libraries in processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004770/how-to-add-external-libraries-in-processing)

The processing sketch seems to work fine but i am getting the following error printed to console every time i run the sketch.

```
No library found for org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresOptimizer
```

This is the Processing PDE Sketch:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresOptimizer.Optimum;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector;

import com.lemmingapex.trilateration.*;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 768);

  double[][] positions = new double[][] { { 8.0, 12.0 }, { 15.0, 40.0 }, { 40.0, 20.0 }, { 22, 40 } };
  double[] distances = new double[] { 10.06, 13.97, 23.32, 10.31 };

  NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver solver = new NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver(new TrilaterationFunction(positions, distances), new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());
  Optimum optimum = solver.solve();

  // the answer
  double[] centroid = optimum.getPoint().toArray();
  printArray(centroid);

  // error and geometry information; may throw SingularMatrixException depending the threshold argument provided
  RealVector standardDeviation = optimum.getSigma(0);
  RealMatrix covarianceMatrix = optimum.getCovariances(0);

  printArray(standardDeviation);
  printArray(covarianceMatrix);

  background(37);
  ellipse((float) centroid[0], (float) centroid[1], 20, 20);
}

void draw() {
}
```

Where am i going wrong? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work using the following imports.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresOptimizer.Optimum;
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer;
import com.lemmingapex.trilateration.NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver;
import com.lemmingapex.trilateration.TrilaterationFunction;
import com.lemmingapex.trilateration.*;
```

Thanks Kevin. Hope this helps other.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004770/how-to-add-external-libraries-in-processing#comment73113133_43007929) on the answer you linked to?

The easiest way to use a library in Processing is to drag the library's `.jar` file into the Processing editor. Just do that for all of the `.jar` files you need. (You might have to delete the library directory you already created first.)

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on using libraries in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674067/873165

Comment: Hi @Kevin

I have dragged and dropped the Lemmingapex and Apache math3 library jar files. I can see Processing creates a code folder in the sketch folder and jar files are place there. 

Now i am having 2 error. 

    The type LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer is ambiguous. 
    No library found for org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquareOptimizer

Please let me know.

Comment: @Werty37 If you have a follow-up question, please post it in its own question post. Please include an updated [mcve] as well as links to the documentation for the library you're using.